# Is a random circuit likely to compute a one-way function?

Tags: one-way-function

I remember reading somewhere that (under certain reasonable assumptions) a Boolean circuit with many inputs and outputs (assume equal number for now) chosen at random will be a one-way function with high probability.  Is this true?

Comment: It depends on how you define random circuit. If you use $n$
block inputs, $m$ NAND gates each with 2 inputs and one output, with the block's outputs these $m$ gate outputs, and randomly connect each of the $2m$ gate inputs to one of the $n+m$ block inputs and gate outputs, you often end up with something that is not a function (two NAND gates can make an RS latch). If you add some rules preventing this, that's a function but not a one-way function. You need to hide many of the outputs to hope for that. I know no quantitative result (hence this is not an answer) [fixed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim that you remember is to good to be true. It is yet unknown (because the question P ?= NP is still open) whether there are one-way functions. If the claim you remember was true, it would prove the existence of one-way functions.

P.S. While P = NP excludes the existence of one-way functions, even with P != NP the existence of one-way functions is still an open problem.

Comment: This is mathematically correct; but from an applied cryptography standpoint, there are one-way functions.

Comment: I would count "the existence of one-way functions" as a reasonable (even if unproven) assumption.

Comment: @fgrieu:  I am explicitly referring to the original question. The vaguely remembered claim about some random circuits as stated by the OP would imply the existence of one-way functions.

Comment: It could be a claim under some widely believed assumption. Although it seems very unlikely for average-case hard OWF, the question is interesting for worst-case hard OWF.

Comment: My question mentioned "reasonable assumptions".  That includes "there is a one-way function".